# Spring security core plugin for grails - Not able to access RequestMap parameters from the database

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have installed grails Spring security core plugin with RequestMap to retrieve URL from the database. I assume I have setup everything as its mentioned in the [guide](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/requestMappings.html#requestmapInstances). When I start my application(http://localhost:8080/scadmin/index/) I get 'sorry, you are not authorized to view this page'. The admin user authenticated properly but RequestMap isnt allowing me to access the url. What's that I am doing wrong? please help.

config.groovy

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'com.tx.sc.auth.User'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'com.tx.sc.auth.UserRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'com.tx.sc.auth.Role'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.requestMap.className = 'com.tx.sc.auth.Requestmap'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType = 'Requestmap'
```

My controller -

```
class AdminController {
    def index() {
        List<Portal> pList = portalService.listAllPortalInfo()
        render(view: "admin", model:[portalList:pList])
    }
}
```

Setting Role

```
def adminRole = new Role(authority: 'ROLE_ADMIN').save(flush: true)
```

Admin User

```
    def adminUser = new User(username: 'admin', password: '12345',email: 'admin@abc.com',enabled: true, accountLocked: false, accountExpired: false, passwordExpired: false).save(flush: true)
```

Map user and role-

```
    if (!adminUser.authorities.contains(adminRole)) {
        UserRole.create(adminUser, adminRole, true)
    }
```

RequestMap-

```
 new Requestmap(url: '/scadmin/admin/index', configAttribute: 'ROLE_ADMIN').save(flush: true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/scadmin/admin/index` should be `/admin/index` - don't include the context.